# Simplified Chinese characters are not displayed correctly in Windows command prompt

Tags: windows-10, unicode, utf-8, chinese

When I enter or paste a simplified Chinese character, it is displayed weirdly. It looks like a 'p' character enclosed in a rectangle. Please see the picture attached.
But I copy the character and paste it in other text editors, it is displayed correctly.
It happens only for simplified Chinese characters, not for traditional.

This started when I checked 'Beta: use Unicode UTF-8 for the support of world langauges' in Change system locale, Country or Region in Settings of Windows 10.

[image: chinese displayed weirdly]

Comment: I don't have an answer but without you actually providing your operating system, nobody else will either.  I can only assume that this is windows but who knows?

Comment: Can you give some example characters?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas As mentioned in the main question and tags, my OS is Windows 10.

Comment: @harrymc The echo command in the question was 你好. The '你' character was not displayed correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the code-page of the Command Prompt to Chinese
with the
[chcp command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chcp):

```
chcp 936
```

Here is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: I have to use multiple languages not only Chinese. In the webpage you referred to, chcp 850 is for multi-language support. I will try this.

Comment: It won't work - 850 is only "Multilingual (**Latin I**)", so basically only European Latin-based languages. You might need to switch code-pages as needed.

Comment: I also checked `chcp 65001` which is UTF-8, but your character only displayed as a place-holder rectangle.